# What do you call these area outside premises for employees to hang out?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some business premises have these small areas just outside the building that employees can go during break to sit, smoke, and hang out. It has benches or picnic tables, garbage cans, and a cover for protection from rain, etc. What do you call these areas? Is there a name for them?

Comment: A smoking area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it isn't a room, you might call it an [*employee break area*](https://www.google.com/search?q=employee%20break%20area&client=firefox-a&hs=67X&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=3kJbUuiPOuPi2QX8hYDwBg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=960&bih=454&dpr=2).

That link is a Google image search for the phrase, which returns several results that fit your description.